# Should terminal server clients use FQDNs with a W2K8 print server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services, print-server, fqdn

We have a network with Windows 2008 R2 Terminal Servers and a print server, and experience printing problems every morning which disappear after a while. The IT department seems to have no idea what the reason could be.

The users connect using RDP and configure their printers using `\\domain\printerId`.

Is it recommended to use the FQDN instead? (`\\my.domain.local\printerId`)?

Comment: it would be valuable to know what kind of printer problems exactly users are experiencing. Also, you suggest that you are using the `\\domain\printer` notation to connect to printers - is the domain controller your print server? Do you have more than one DC in your domain? Are you using Group Policy or scripts to connect to printers? If so, what is your exact configuration / command line to connect?

Comment: Yeah, not really enough information here to propose a good theory.  (Maybe why your IT department doesn't know either).  You can always try connecting via FQDN or IP, but I wouldn't get my hopes up on that working.

Comment: you should not have to use an FQDN, as long as name resolution is working

Comment: the short answer would be 'it should work either way but you should not waste your time typing extra characters'.If your IT dpt can't fix it I think they may be in the wrong trade.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just try it out and see if it solves your problem?

In general, I am in favour of FQDN's over Netbios names.